# Could not create server TCP listening socket *:6383 bind: Cannot assign requested address in redis clustering on docker (in windows)

Tags: docker, redis

I'm trying to set up redis clustring on windows docker.
it works fine only in **redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6383 inside docker container CLI** all nodes are fine and cluster has no problem. this is one of the redis.config file nodes

> redis.config file

```
port 6383
bind 0.0.0.0
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf 
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes
```

**The problem is** with the above configuration, it's not possible to access the clustering with the application because it's not reachable for app (this app works fine in redis single mode)

when I change "bind" redis.conf file to my computer ip which is 192.168.3.205 i get this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUgEG.jpg)

I have tried the following:

1. open the above port in the firewall roll
2. with **telnet** command it seems nobody listennign on this port

> telnet 192.168.3.205 6383 and 127.0.0.1 6383

3. in ***netstat*** prot 6383 not used by anyone

and this is my .yml file

```html
version: "3.8"

networks:
  default:
    name: amin-cluster

services:
  redis0:
    container_name: node-0
    image: mnadeem/redis 
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
    - C:\Windows\System32\6379\redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    command: ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: node-0
    restart: always
  redis1:
    container_name: node-1
    image: mnadeem/redis 
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes: 
    - C:\Windows\System32\6380\redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    command: ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: node-1
    restart: always
  redis2:
    container_name: node-2
    image: mnadeem/redis 
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes: 
    - C:\Windows\System32\6381\redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    command: ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: node-2
    restart: always
  redis3:
    container_name: node-3
    image: mnadeem/redis 
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
     - C:\Windows\System32\6382\redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    command: ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: node-3
    restart: always
  redis4:
    container_name: node-4
    image: mnadeem/redis 
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
    - C:\Windows\System32\6383\redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    command: ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: node-4
    restart: always
  redis5:
    container_name: node-5
    image: mnadeem/redis 
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes: 
    - C:\Windows\System32\6384\redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    command: ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: node-5
    restart: always
```

Comment: Can you show how you're starting the container?  You most likely forgot to publish the port (which binds the host port to the container port)

Comment: @Matthew I set the port inside the redis.conf file and then I use  ">docker-compose up -d " do I need to set the port somewhere else or how do I suppose to tell the container to start at a specific port.  in single-mode, I pick the image name the container, and tell the port like 6060:6379 but here I don't know

Comment: I added an answer that should help, also the standard redis images provided by the redis team themselves are pretty solid, any particular reason to use a 3rd party image?  (mnadeem/redis), edit: nvm I see that those images are geared towards clustering.

Comment: @Matthew sorry I couldn't find any clustering configuration for docker in its document. I'm still working on it I seem to be stuck do you have any guidance to implement Redis cluster on docker with this standard Redis image?

Comment: Not sure, but if you want more help with that you should ask a second question.  For the immediate problem regarding accessing the port, does the answer I've provided solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your docker compose yml, you need to publish the port, and set one up for each service you want accessible from the host.

```
redis0:
    ports:
      - "6383:6383"
    ...
redis1:
    ports:
      - "12345:6383"
```

The syntax is "hostport:containerport", since you have 6 redis instances, assuming you want each accessable each host port will need to be different.

You can obviously omit ports if you don't need it accessible from the host.

For more details on how to publish ports, read the docker compose yml docs https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports

Comment: thanks to you I pass the problem but not completely. I have another problem when trying to config nodes with the command "redis-cli --cluster create <my ip>: <port> ... " automatically assign an IP like  172.21.0.1  instead of the IP i gave to it

Comment: @aminrahmati I suggest you resolve this question and create a new one with your new problem.  StackOverflow's best used when asking a specific question and getting a specific answer, and you'll most likely not get a lot of traction by asking follow up questions to an existing question.